# Modifying owl:inverseOf using statement owl:inverseOf owl:inverseOf owl:inverseOf?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

Trying to include this in my knowledge base:

```
owl:inverseOf owl:inverseOf owl:inverseOf
```

How will this effect the functioning of `owl:inverseOf` once such a statement is made in the knowledgebase? Is this modification locally possible?

---

The answer we came up with is that the statement will alter the `inverseOf` property modifier such that the new properties between which `inverseOf` is applied will now make them symmetric to each other. **Is this correct?** Please verify.

Comment: That should affect what? OWL DL reasoning? You can't hijack OWL 2 DL semantics - obviously, there were some good reasons for the current definition of its semantics. Tableau reasoning won't use any of those hacks - the expansion rules are fixed and well-defined - OWL built-in keywords are fixed and well defined, etc ...

Comment: yes how will the reasoning change, whatever effect it has please mention.

Comment: The last occurence says `inverserOf` -- typo or intentional?

Comment: it was a typo, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reserved vocabulary in axioms - e.g., trying to change the semantics of language defined properties - is an OWL 2 DL violation and won't be supported by any reasoner which only supports that profile. Most reasoners will ignore it, but they can also choose to throw an exception.

In other words, no effect or an error, depending on implementation choices.